# What is the correct way to transform the formula for the determination of the day of the week into C++?

Tags: c++, date, formula

I have an assignment where I need to figure out which day of the week a date was/is. The formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week?oldformat=true) goes as following

[image]

where

```
d = day (1-31)  
m = month (starting with March = 1 up to February=12)  
y = last 2 digits of a year  
c = first 2 digits of a year
```

(y and c must be reduced by 1 if the month is January or February)

My function goes as follows:

```
int wochentagWiki(int inttag, int intmonat, int intjahr) {
int d = inttag;

int m = 0;

switch (intmonat) {
case 1:
    m = 11;
    break;
case 2:
    m = 12;
    break;
case 3:
    m = 1;
    break;
case 4:
    m = 2;
    break;
case 5:
    m = 3;
    break;
case 6:
    m = 4;
    break;
case 7:
    m = 5;
    break;
case 8:
    m = 6;
    break;
case 9:
    m = 7;
    break;
case 10:
    m = 8;
    break;
case 11:
    m = 9;
    break;
case 12:
    m = 10;
    break;
}

int y = intjahr % 100;
if (intmonat == 1 || intmonat == 2) {
    y--;
}

int c = intjahr / 100;
if (intmonat == 1 || intmonat == 2) {
    c--;
}

int w = (d + (2.6 * m - 0.2) + y + (y / 4) + (c / 4) - (__int64)2 * c) % 7;

return w;
}
```

My problem is that w always returns a wrong value, and I think it's because I translated the formula the wrong way. What would be the correct way to write it down?

Comment: use pen and paper for an example where you get wrong result, then use a debugger to step through your code and see where the code deviates from what you expect

Comment: i dont understand `case 1: m = 11;` and the others, shouldnt you subtract 1 (not 2) ? btw all those cases can be combined to `m = (intmonat + 12 - 2) % 12 + 1` and I think it should be `m = (intmonat + 12 -1) % 12 + 1;`

Comment: Using `m = (intmonat + 12 - 2) % 12` really shortens everything, thanks for that, but sadly both result in a wrong result. I tried it with only that part `(2.6 * m - 0.2);` but sadly both versions result in a wrong result. 4 for example should return 10, but it either returns 5 or 7, depending on if I use -1 or -2

Comment: it is off by one, I tried to fix it in the comment, but it is still off by one. I always get it wrong with `%`, but using a debugger it is simple to fix

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you've made a mistake in copying down the formula:

> (y and c must be reduced by 1 if the month is January or February)

But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week?oldformat=true) says:

> - Y is the year minus 1 for January or February, and the year for any other month
> - y is the last 2 digits of Y
> - c is the first 2 digits of Y